# Remove duplicate files using Hash in Python. Work perfectly fine for English Document but not Chinese Document

Tags: python, hash, duplicates

I have looked up numerous sources and able to remove the duplicate files for the common extension types which is in the English document. However, I am not able to run the same code for the Chinese Document, anyways I can work this out? open(filename, "rb", encoding="utf-8") doesn't resolve my issue based on some answers from other question on StackOverflow.

Thank you.

```
import os
import datetime
import hashlib

def chunk_reader(fobj, chunk_size=2048):
    # Generator that reads a file in chunks of bytes
    while True:
        chunk = fobj.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk


def get_hash(_file, chunk_size=2048, hash=hashlib.sha1):
    hashobj = hash()
    with open(_file, 'rb') as file_object:
        hashobj.update(file_object.read(chunk_size))
        ##for chunk in chunk_reader(file_object, chunk_size=chunk_size):
        ##    hashobj.update(chunk)
    _hash = hashobj.digest()
    return _hash
```

Source code:
https://www.darkartistry.com/2018/12/review-or-delete-duplicate-files-with-python/

Comment: So, where is the code? What does it suppose to do? And what does it do instead?

Comment: Calculate the hash value for each file, compare if there is same hash value. If hash value is the same, meaning there is a duplicate file, this script will remove the duplicated file. Code attached.

Comment: Equal hash values do **not** mean identical files.  They mean that the files *may* be identical.  You actually have to compare the files themselves to be sure.  It is a bit like comparing file lengths.  Files with the same length might not be identical, though they can be. Files with different lengths are definitely not identical.

Comment: Understand your point, there could be some cases, the file may not be identical, but for my dataset, it is working fine. Hence, that is not my consideration, my consideration now is how to make it work in Chinese.

Comment: @rossum Hash functions are specifically designed to prevent collisions, and they are large enough that the odds of two different strings randomly hashing to the same value are for the purposes of a question like this, impossible. For OP: What exactly is the unexpected behavior on Chinese documents?

Comment: If you make a copy of one of these files and grab the hash for both, you are seeing different hashes come back?

Comment: I think the given methods should work for any language assuming you uncommented the for loop. Since you read your files in binary, Python doesn't even see the content as a string. What is the problem for Chinese documents here? Does it give an error or no error but it doesn't remove duplicates?

Comment: This is the error message when run with Chinese Document


"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u5e74' in position 12: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: @JNevill, same hash value even if the file name is different but with the same content, this is working as expected.

Comment: Show the whole error stack trace. Likely the error doesn't happen in this code.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Leong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]


"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u5e74' in position 12: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Line 19 refers to the "if not chunk" in the above code

Comment: So you're telling us that you put your code into Python's cp1252.py file? Why on earth would you do that?

Comment: @Manuel, in which part of my code put in cp1252??? If I know the answer, why should I post my question here. I resolve the issue by the way.

Comment: The part of the stack trace that you showed says that that line 19 is in that file, and you're saying that that line 19 refers to your code. Thus you're saying that your line is in that file.

Comment: (encoding='utf-8-sig') solved this issue.